# Javascript - Ternary Operator - Comparing same function twice?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, ternary-operator

I have 3 variables `top, mid, bot` that I want to be logged depending on which part the `div` pops up (if topmost part of `div`, then `top` would be logged)

All you need to know is as the user scrolls down from the top of page, there are certain `divs` that we want to target. The 3 variables represent what needs to be logged whenever we hit a certain part of the div.

How would rewrite the `console.log` ternary operator to make sense, right now, the mid is not being run at all.

**EDIT**

`trgt1 and trgt2` are 2 divs with the class (`.column`). `trgt1` is the very first div that shows up, `trgt2` should pop up as we scroll through halfway through the div.

**CODE**

```
function onScroll(event){

let top = "Column with id:`id-10` started to become visible on the page."
let mid = "Column with id:`id-50` is now more than 50% visible on the page."
let bot = "Column with id:`id-40` is now fully visible on the page."

targets.forEach(

    function(trgt,index){

          let isVisible = isScrolledIntoView(trgt);

          if (visibleStates[index] != isVisible)

          console.log(`Element index ${index} is now ${isVisible === trgt1 ? top : (isVisible === trgt2 ? mid : bot)}`);

          visibleStates[index] = isVisible;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Is your question how to write a switch statement in javascript? If so, I'm sure you can research for the answer.

Comment: I'd like to rewrite the ternary operator to be able to trigger 3 conditionals based off the function being put in

Comment: What values will trigger top, mid and bot...

Comment: Start with the least likely, then go backwards. Div 3 is least likely, check that, if no, check 2, if no, check 1  ${isVisible ? bot : (isVisible ? mid : top)}

Comment: Appreciate that, but it seems like as it is written, either way, only one thing gets logged as I'm scrolling down the page.

Comment: You're trying to get three different outcomes, from two nested ternary statements which share the same condition... this is not possible. You will only every get two outcomes..... isVisible ? bot : (<someOtherConditionIsRequired> ? mid : top)

Comment: ok, so if my `isVisible` function checks where I am in the viewport, what could I do to be able to use that same checking method to determine if I'm at the mid or top of the div? Not sure if that made sense

Comment: isVisible is being used as a value not a function.... none of this makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

You could work with a script that runs on scrolling the page. So add an eventlistener to the page.. Then you can debounce the scrolling, so control the amount of noise you allow on the window.. The function I have included is a working debounce function, just play with the wait in milliseconds. And then use your debounce function on the checkSlide() function where you put your running code in.

I know this is not a direct answer, it is another way of approaching the problem. This could work. If you want to do it your way, go for it..

Good luck!

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(checkSlide));

function checkSlide(){}

function debounce(func, wait=20, immediate = true){

var timeout; 

//debounce is a higher order function and will return another function 
return function run_code() {
    var context = this;

    //arguments is local variable of a function, refers to all arguments 
    var args = arguments; 

    //variable later is a function
    var later = function(){
        timeout = null;

        //if it is not time zero, apply checkSlide function 
        if(!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var Callnow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if(Callnow) func.apply(context, args);
}
}
```